# Python sched error TypeError: enter() takes exactly 5 arguments (4 given)

Tags: python, scheduler

The python script was working on my Windows machine, but I uploaded to my Ubuntu vps and now get this error.

Sched docs say there should only be 4 arguments?

Comment: How could we possibly help you without seeing your code?

Comment: If I had to guess without seeing your code, I would assume that you're passing only four arguments to the `enter()` method when you should be providing five.

Answer (score 1):

You have Python 2.7 on your Ubuntu while probably having some 3.x version on your Windows machine.

Scheduler `.enter()` takes exactly 4 *explicit* arguments in 2.7: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sched.html#module-sched

The 1st argument of a method is `self` so that makes 5 non-optional arguments on 2.7. You should either install the same interpreter version or take care of handling cross-platform concerns in your code.